# Evaluate img src before load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function that writes an `<img>` to an html file. The `src` of this file is a third party app, and depending on what that src url returns, that's the `.gif` that appears.

Is there a way to set this as a variable, evaluate what gets returned, and then perform operations based on which picture is returned?

**Current code**

```
 document.write(unescape('%3Cimg alt="chat" src="' + (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//cbi.boldchat.com/aid/149585914643539/bc.cbi?cbdid=4329063963095645" border="0" id=' + bccbId + ' /%3E'));
```

**Desired outcome**

```
var v = eval(unescape('%3Cimg alt="chat" src="' + (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//cbi.boldchat.com/aid/149585914646039/bc.cbi?cbdid=4329063963095645" border="0" id=' + bccbId + ' /%3E'));

if(v.indexOf("clear") > -1)
 do x
else 
 do y
```

Comment: What ends up being the src attribute is right there as an expression and already gets evaluated - do you want to look at the content of the picture that is returned or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yes. The current `src` is a call to the application which based on some logic returns a different picture. exg. depending on the conditions it could return `alert.gif` `stable.gif` etc.  And I need to make decisions based on those conditions.

Comment: Does the third-party service allow CORS? If not there is no legitimate way to access much information about the picture via the browser, at most you can get its size (width, height). In that case you'd need to use server-side code. Or preferably find out if they have an API, and use that.

Comment: You should look into promises